# Perl Time::HiRes - the best way to replace regular alarm

Tags: perl, timeout, alarm, time-hires

I need to implement less-than-a-second timeouts in the DBIx::HA package. Having the following code from that module:

```
my $timeout = 0;
eval {
    no strict;
    my $h = set_sig_handler(
        'ALRM', 
        sub { $timeout = 1; die 'TIMEOUT'; },
        { mask=>['ALRM'], safe=>1 }
    );
    alarm($DATABASE::conf{_getdbname($dsn)}->{'connecttimeout'});
    $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $auth, $attrs);
    alarm(0);
};
```

I know that there is a core Perl module Time::HiRes, but I never used it before. It also has an `alarm()` sub - may I just insert `use Time::HiRes qw (alarm);` before the lines above? Or maybe I should somehow adapt the lines above? I haven't found any obvious example.

Comment: Have you tried it? :)

Comment: @simbabque Already yes :) I was a bit (very) pessimistic, but after reading the docs more carefully I've got to those lines ("This function can be imported...") too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly as you said. All you need to do is load Time::HiRes and import `alarm` before you call the code. But please don't put it directly above the code, it's not good practice to have `use` statements all over the place. It belongs to the top.

[The Time::HiRes doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes#alarm-floating_seconds-interval_floating_seconds) says (**emphazis mine**):

> #### alarm ( $floating_seconds [, $interval_floating_seconds ] )
>
> The SIGALRM signal is sent after the specified number of seconds. Implemented using setitimer() if available, ualarm() if not. The $interval_floating_seconds argument is optional and will be zero if unspecified, resulting in alarm()-like behaviour. **This function can be imported, resulting in a nice drop-in replacement for the alarm provided with perl**, see the "EXAMPLES" below.

Then later on there is [this example](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes#EXAMPLES) (quoted verbatim) that nicely shows that you can use floating-point values with `alarm` now.

```
use Time::HiRes qw ( time alarm sleep );
$now_fractions = time;
sleep (2.5);
alarm (10.6666666);
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm still having some minor issues, but I doubt they are connected to Time::HiRes, and in general the following solution actually works:

```
use Time::HiRes qw (alarm); # Just adding this line.... ;)
my $timeout = 0;
eval {
    no strict;
    my $h = set_sig_handler(
        'ALRM', 
        sub { $timeout = 1; die 'TIMEOUT'; },
        { mask=>['ALRM'], safe=>1 }
    );
    alarm($DATABASE::conf{_getdbname($dsn)}->{'connecttimeout'});
    $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $auth, $attrs);
    alarm(0);
};
```

Good to know! :D